# iOS TableView wrong indexPath when selecting cell with keyboard shown

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have tableView size set by AutoLayout (bottom to Bottom Layout Guide, top to another view and so on but first UISearchBar to Top Layout Guide):
[image: My tableView]

Controller with tableView:

[image: Controller settings]

I need to change table offset when keyboard is shown so I have these two methods:

```
// MARK: - Keyboard
func keyboardWasShown (notification: NSNotification) {
    let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden (notification: NSNotification) {
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

And it's working but I have problem when keyboard is shown. The last item can't be selected and instead of that I get previous item. I tapped where is last item and it should navigate to detail page with last item but instead I see detail page with previous item. It isn't shift for all items but just for the last one and when I filtered to just one item it's working okay. When keyboard is hidden (and items are still filtered) then It's okay too (it selects the right thing). So I guess the problem must be here:

```
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset
```

So where could be problem? Thanks for help

Comment: I think you should also update the top height to fit the search bar and the segmented control.

Comment: Nope, I just tried it and it didn't help and when I scroll to top I have too big white space there.

Comment: Have you tried adding extra space from `viewDidLoad:`?

Comment: What you mean by that?

Comment: Since top space is fixed (it's the height of the search bar plus the height of the segmented control), you can update the `tableView.contentInset` from the `viewDidLoad:` method of your view controller.

Comment: I can set it there but if I set top inset there I must change tableView top constraint to Top Layout Guide and after that content of tableView would be scrolling under search bar and segment control and I tried it and same problem. When I don't set contentInset, when keyboard is visible I don't almost see last item but when I tried to tap on little part which is visible it's working alright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my solution. I was using `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and method `keyboardWillBeHidden` was called before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so `contentInset` of `tableView` was set back to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` and then there was wrong indexPath. So now I use `keyboardDidHide` instead of `keyboardWillBeHidden`:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidHide:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

...

func keyboardDidHide (notification: NSNotification) {     
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, assuming `keyboardHeight` is storing your keyboard height (pay attention because the keyboard frame may vary across devices), try this:

```
CGRect *frame = [tableView frame];
frame.size.height -= keyboardHeight;
[tableView setFrame:frame]
```

Do the same thing (but replace `-=` with `+=`) when keyboard hides.

Comment: It didn't help for some reason I had wrong bottom offset. But thanks for help it helps me find solution.